# Add text to the first row of .csv file in Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, csv

I'm executing the following script in my `.bat` file:

```
*ren design.csv test.txt
echo ImportSheetType=BOM>test.txt
type test.txt >> design.csv*
```

However, my text `ImportSheetType=BOM` always get appended at the end of the `design.csv` file

How can I add my text line to the `.csv` file so that it would appear in the first row by itself if I were to open the `.csv` file in a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but based on the headline , I think you want

```
 rem examine data.csv
 type data.csv
 1,2,3
 4,5,6

 echo  ImportSheetType=BOM>fixed.csv
 type data.csv >> fixed.csv

 rem examine fixed file
 type fixed.csv
 ImportSheetType=BOM
 1,2,3
 4,5,6
```

I've changed the names of the files to be self-documenting, to indicate the purpose they serve in creating your final file. Just follow this pattern, and use the names you really need.

I hope this helps.